# How to retain plot layout characteristics when using ggplot in Shiny?

Tags: r, canvas, ggplot2, shiny

When making a straightforward ggplot, the canvas size will extend so that the height of the plot is appropriate, allowing for some spacing between variables. For example, if I have 10 variables I need to show on one plot, everything is plotted nicely:

[image]

Time to do some Shiny! Let's see if I can embed this plot in a tabPanel.

Here we go:
[image]

Looks great, but now my horizontal segments all look cramped together like a pack of hotdogs. There is no whitespace between the horizontal `geom_segments`.

This issue constantly plagues me.

I feel like ggplot has a brain of it's own, when it comes to canvas sizes, which is fine, but I can't pry the skull off to appropriately control how it will plot itself.

To quote [Forrest R. Stevens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4208752/forrest-r-stevens),
"...the key to getting consistent canvas and all other dimensions is to control the graphic output device directly."

I totally agree with him and used his excellent advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086737/how-can-i-control-the-canvas-size-in-ggplot), yet there is no way to control this since we are using Shiny.

Next I attempted to play with the values in

```
           p <- p + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm")
           p <- p + panel.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"))
```

but alas it did no good; it merely created margins and further crunched things together, which makes perfect sense.

My question is this -- how can I change my ggplot so that it appears in Shiny with proper spacing?

**Good looking ggplot, not in Shiny:**

```
  library("shiny")
  library("ggplot2")

  DF_for_plotting <- structure(list(col1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), col2 = c(100, 
                                                                  100, 61.9433678425096, 10.7823906941804, 4.18175346165306, 3.24251454697229, 
                                                                  6.68573373055455, 14.945119260922, 18.9296271776082, 11.0742379220636
  ), col3 = c(100, 100, 100, 12.8418470680653, 5.31239161296286, 
              4.42025167250118, 10.699998838647, 27.5067118056336, 20.6360723198699, 
              13.1476876837599), col4 = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
                                          100, 100, 100)), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"), row.names = c("one", 
                                                                                                                     "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", 
                                                                                                                     "ten"), class = "data.frame")

  hex=c("#CC0000", "#90BD31", "#178CCB")
  textsize <- c(9)
  number_of_variables <- 5

  p <- ggplot()
  p <- p + scale_y_discrete(breaks = seq(10), labels = c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five"))

  breaks=c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100)
  break_labels=c("0%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%")

  p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks, labels=break_labels, name=percent_correct)

  ### inner loop
  for (varnum in seq(1:number_of_variables)){ #<-- we are already in the Tab. Now we need to make all three segments for all three variables for this tab

  p <- p + geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes_q(x=DF_for_plotting$col1[varnum], xend=DF_for_plotting$col2[varnum]-0.001, y=varnum, yend=varnum, colour='impaired'), size=textsize*2.5) +
    geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes_q(x=DF_for_plotting$col2[varnum], xend=DF_for_plotting$col3[varnum]-0.001, y=varnum, yend=varnum, colour='normal'), size=textsize*2.5) +
    geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes_q(x=DF_for_plotting$col3[varnum], xend=DF_for_plotting$col4[varnum]-0.001, y=varnum, yend=varnum, colour='optimal'), size=textsize*2.5)
  p <- p + scale_color_manual(values=c(impaired=hex[1], normal=hex[2], optimal=hex[3], white='#ffffff'), name="Function Key")
  }
  p
```

**UI.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme='test.css',

    fluidRow(
    column(2, 
           fluidRow(
             h3("Select Customer:"),
                    wellPanel(class="info", numericInput(inputId="num", label="Select ID:", value=NaN),
                              if(show_age_slider=='Yes'){textOutput("")},
                              if(show_edu_slider=='Yes'){textOutput("")},
                              if(show_gender_buttons=='Yes'){textOutput("")}
                    ))),

    #do.call will call the navbarPage function with the arguments in the tabs list
    shinyUI(fluidRow(
      column(12,
             "", 
             do.call(navbarPage,tabs)
    ))))))
```

**SERVER.R**

```
library("shiny")
library("ggplot2")

DF_for_plotting <- structure(list(col1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), col2 = c(100, 
                                                                                   100, 61.9433678425096, 10.7823906941804, 4.18175346165306, 3.24251454697229, 
                                                                                   6.68573373055455, 14.945119260922, 18.9296271776082, 11.0742379220636
), col3 = c(100, 100, 100, 12.8418470680653, 5.31239161296286, 
            4.42025167250118, 10.699998838647, 27.5067118056336, 20.6360723198699, 
            13.1476876837599), col4 = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
                                        100, 100, 100)), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"), row.names = c("one", 
                                                                                                                   "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", 
                                                                                                                   "ten"), class = "data.frame")


hex=c("#CC0000", "#90BD31", "#178CCB")
textsize=c(8)

############## shiny server starts here: #######################################################################
shinyServer(function(input, output) {  

# begin the observe() block
observe(


lapply(seq(1:number_of_tabs),function(i) output[[paste0("plot",i)]] <- renderPlot({   #<-- lapply will fill up each tab and create one ggplot
  plotindex <<- 0
  list_of_ggplots <<- list() #although we only have one tab, we could easily extend to having multiple tabs
  p <- ggplot()

breaks=c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 115, 130)
break_labels=c("0%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%")

number_of_variables <- 10

### inner loop
  for (varnum in seq(1:number_of_variables)){ #<-- We need to make all three segments for all three variables for this tab

    p <- p + scale_y_discrete(breaks = seq(10), labels = c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"))



    p <- p + geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes_q(x=DF_for_plotting$col1[varnum], xend=DF_for_plotting$col2[varnum]-0.001, y=varnum, yend=varnum, colour='impaired'), size=textsize*2.5) +
      geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes_q(x=DF_for_plotting$col2[varnum], xend=DF_for_plotting$col3[varnum]-0.001, y=varnum, yend=varnum, colour='normal'), size=textsize*2.5) +
      geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes_q(x=DF_for_plotting$col3[varnum], xend=DF_for_plotting$col4[varnum]-0.001, y=varnum, yend=varnum, colour='optimal'), size=textsize*2.5)
    p <- p + scale_color_manual(values=c(impaired=hex[1], normal=hex[2], optimal=hex[3], white='#ffffff'), name="Function Key")
#    p <- p + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"))
#    p <- p + theme(panel.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"))

            list_of_ggplots[["to_UI"]] <<- p # this is strange but true; apparently any arbitrary key works for inserting the plot into the list_of_ggplots
}   
      print(list_of_ggplots)  #<-- to send out to UI
})
)


) #<-- end of observe function
}  #<-- end of brace in shinyserver function
)  #<-- end the shinyserver function
```

Comment: The panel margin isn't really controlling the size of the graphics device. Try setting `height` and `width` in `renderPlot` and scaling those up and down until they look right.

Comment: @Gregor: So close!! This helped by giving me a scrollbar on the right -- but this didn't really enlarge the space: 
http://postimg.org/image/438ey3rrv/