# How can I display my plot without toolbars, in Shiny?

Tags: html, css, r, twitter-bootstrap-3, shiny

This question is an extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178585/how-to-retain-plot-layout-characteristics-when-using-ggplot-in-shiny) question.

I am plotting a rather large gglot in Shiny.

Using `renderPlot(width = 1500, height = 1000, ...` I am able to show the whole plot; however, I now have a scrollbar on the right. I would like to extend the height of the column in the fluidRow, rather than have this scrollbar.

[image]

From what I understand, Shiny (aka bootstrap) should dynamically size the height of the fluidRow to whatever the size of the plot is. Why is my visible area so small? Scrollbars are nice, but I want the whole plot to be visible.

**UI.R**

```
source("helper.R")    
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme='test.css',

    fluidRow(
    column(2, 
           fluidRow(
             h3("Select Customer:"),
                    wellPanel(class="info", numericInput(inputId="num", label="Select ID:", value=NaN),
                              if(show_age_slider=='Yes'){textOutput("")},
                              if(show_edu_slider=='Yes'){textOutput("")},
                              if(show_gender_buttons=='Yes'){textOutput("")}
                    ))),

    #do.call will call the navbarPage function with the arguments in the tabs list
    shinyUI(fluidRow(
      column(12,
             "", 
             do.call(navbarPage,tabs)
    ))))))
```

**SERVER.R**

```
library("shiny")
library("ggplot2")

DF_for_plotting <- structure(list(col1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), col2 = c(100, 
                                                                                   100, 61.9433678425096, 10.7823906941804, 4.18175346165306, 3.24251454697229, 
                                                                                   6.68573373055455, 14.945119260922, 18.9296271776082, 11.0742379220636
), col3 = c(100, 100, 100, 12.8418470680653, 5.31239161296286, 
            4.42025167250118, 10.699998838647, 27.5067118056336, 20.6360723198699, 
            13.1476876837599), col4 = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
                                        100, 100, 100)), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"), row.names = c("one", 
                                                                                                                   "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", 
                                                                                                                   "ten"), class = "data.frame")


hex=c("#CC0000", "#90BD31", "#178CCB")
textsize=c(8)

############## shiny server starts here: #######################################################################
shinyServer(function(input, output) {  

# begin the observe() block
observe(


lapply(seq(1:number_of_tabs),function(i) output[[paste0("plot",i)]] <- renderPlot(width = 1500,
                                                                                  height = 1000,{   #<-- lapply will fill up each tab and create one ggplot

  plotindex <<- 0
  list_of_ggplots <<- list() #although we only have one tab, we could easily extend to having multiple tabs
  p <- ggplot()

breaks=c(0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 115, 130)
break_labels=c("0%", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%")

number_of_variables <- 10

### inner loop
  for (varnum in seq(1:number_of_variables)){ #<-- We need to make all three segments for all three variables for this tab

    p <- p + scale_y_discrete(breaks = seq(10), labels = c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"))



    p <- p + geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes_q(x=DF_for_plotting$col1[varnum], xend=DF_for_plotting$col2[varnum]-0.001, y=varnum, yend=varnum, colour='impaired'), size=textsize*2.5) +
      geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes_q(x=DF_for_plotting$col2[varnum], xend=DF_for_plotting$col3[varnum]-0.001, y=varnum, yend=varnum, colour='normal'), size=textsize*2.5) +
      geom_segment(data=DF_for_plotting, aes_q(x=DF_for_plotting$col3[varnum], xend=DF_for_plotting$col4[varnum]-0.001, y=varnum, yend=varnum, colour='optimal'), size=textsize*2.5)
    p <- p + scale_color_manual(values=c(impaired=hex[1], normal=hex[2], optimal=hex[3], white='#ffffff'), name="Function Key")
#    p <- p + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"))
#    p <- p + theme(panel.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"))

            list_of_ggplots[["to_UI"]] <<- p # this is strange but true; apparently any arbitrary key works for inserting the plot into the list_of_ggplots
}   
      print(list_of_ggplots)  #<-- to send out to UI
})
)


) #<-- end of observe function
}  #<-- end of brace in shinyserver function
)  #<-- end the shinyserver function
```

**helper.R**

```
show_gender_buttons='No'
show_edu_slider='No'
show_age_slider='No'
##############################################
### this part is to create the UI properly ###

#tab_names <- c("", tab_names)
#make a list of all the arguments you want to pass to the navbarPage function
tabs<-list()


#first element will be the title, empty in our case
tabs[[1]]=""

#add all the tabPanels to the list
for (j in 2:(number_of_tabs+1)){
     tabs[[j]]=tabPanel(tab_names[j],plotOutput(paste0("plot",j-1)))}

################################################
```

Comment: too many shinyUI functions? Does it work better if you remove that?

Comment: You can try adding to your UI.R: tags$style(type="text/css", ".tab-content { overflow: visible; }"), # to avoid the scroll bars

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't post your `theme.css`, but the issue is probably that the css `overflow` argument is set to `scroll` for the `div` holding the plots in you app's css. This forces scrollbars if the div is too small for its content.

The default `height` for a `plotOutput` is set to 400px, so in your `renderPlot` if you set the height to 1000 you will get a scrollbar if the overflow of the div is set to scroll.

Try setting the height argument of `plotOutput` to 1000px or more for example:

```
#add all the tabPanels to the list
for (i in 2:(number_of_tabPages+1)){
  tabs[[i]]=tabPanel(paste0("Tab",i-1),plotOutput(paste0("plot",i-1),height="1100px"))

}
```

Should give something like this:

[image]

You can also try finding what sets the `overflow` to `scroll` for this div. I'm just suspecting this because when the code is run without the `theme.css` it looks fine without changing your code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. 1 thing:   Strangely enough, when I comment out `theme='test.css'`, nothing changes and my problem persists. Am I missing something? Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure what's happening then, I tested this  shiny_0.11.1, what version are you running this on?

Comment: I am using shiny_0.10.2.1.  Maybe I should upgrade and try again