# R: Adding rectangular border around plot and legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, border

I know I am missing something very simple but I can't seem to figure it out and I can't find it anywhere online. I'm new to R, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code is as follows:

```
graph1<-ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data=df,colour="black",aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,fill=ALG))+
  ggtitle("Figure 2.2A: Assessment Results for\nGeneral Aquatic Life Use, Spatial Extent")+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("")+
  coord_equal()+
  scale_fill_manual("Aquatic Life Designated\nUse 2014 Assessment",values=c((values=c(colors))))+
  cowplot::background_grid(major= "none",minor = "none") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA),
        legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=8, face="bold"),
        plot.title=element_text(size=15, face="bold",vjust=1.0,hjust = .3))
```

This is what I'm getting:
[image]

How do I get the legend to be inside the border???

Comment: Take a look at the [ggplot2 doumentation on adjusting theme elements](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html)

Comment: I did.... @JanBoyer

Comment: Look at it again. There's a section that describes exactly what you're looking for. `Or place inside the plot using relative coordinates between 0 and 1`.

Comment: Would you be so kind and direct me where? Because nothing has worked for me. @Anonymouscoward

Comment: The obvious response to "nothing has worked for me" is what do you mean by "nothing".

Comment: I pasted the sentence you could use to do a ctrl-find to direct you to the exact part of the page. Search for this sentence: "Or place inside the plot using relative coordinates between 0 and 1."

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `theme(legend.position=c(0.5,0.6))` You'll have to change the numbers to position the legend. The values will be between 0 and 1 for both the x and y variable in the argument `theme(legend.position=c(x,y))`.

Comment: Thanks! However, I would like to keep the position of my legend where it is.. I just want to make the rectangular border wider to include it. Is this not possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086737/how-can-i-control-the-canvas-size-in-ggplot see this question

Comment: Thanks @ Nick Dylla