# Setting canvas size in ggsave to a fixed width while maintaining aspect ratio of plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Long story short, I make youtube videos for my students and I produce a lot of graphics. Up until now, I have imported the images into premiere, resized them, then placed a separate white background image behind the ggplot graphics. This is a bit tedious and I would love to be able to export directly from R into the appropriate size (1920x1080 p) so I don't have to resize and add a background image.

I was able to resize the graphic, but now it stretches it:

[image]

I want it to look like this (I put the box around the image and the canvas to make it clearer where the plot ends and the background canvas begins):

[image]

I know I can specify the outside margins (see [How can I control the canvas size in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086737/how-can-i-control-the-canvas-size-in-ggplot)), but that would require me setting the outside margins per plot; Sometimes I have plots that are wider than they are tall and sometimes I have plots that are taller than they are wide. ggsave seems to respect the aspect ratio and maximizes one dimension or the other.

So how do I set the outside margins while maintaining the correct aspect ratio?

Comment: Quick question: are you using coord_fixed() to control the aspect ratio?

Comment: Not currently. I thought about doing something like that, but unfortunately I often combine plots (e.g., using cowplot::plot_grid) and I don't see how to fix the aspect ratio of each individual plot

Answer (score 1):

You could set the panel size to a specific value,

```
library(egg)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

p <- ggplot() + labs(x = 'x title', y = 'y title')

ggsave('notset.png', p, width = 6.4, height = 3.6, units = 'in', dpi = 300)

ggsave('set.png', egg::set_panel_size(p, width=unit(4, "in"), height=unit(3, "in")), 
       width = 6.4, height = 3.6, units = 'in', dpi = 300)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. The problem is that the set_panel_size must be specified. That value will change from plot to plot and I'm not sure how to automate that.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want the plot size to be. On one hand you don't want to specify the plot margin, but you also don't want to specify the panel size. So how is the computer going to know what you want the plot size to be within that fixed device region? Or do you just care about the aspect ratio and want the plot to scale so as to fill the height or width?

Comment: "Or do you just care about the aspect ratio and want the plot to scale so as to fill the height or width?" -- that's exactly what I want: maintain the aspect ratio, fill the height (or width) to the maximum dimension, then put the right amount of white space for the other. Does that make sense?